# Fetch mongo documents based on multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given mongo document of the following form in a collection:

```
{
  "_id":"ObjectId",
  "value":{
    "id": 1,
     "payment": [
       {
        "status": {
           "id": "1.1",
           "value": "Paid"
         }
      },
      {
       "status": {
           "id": "1.2",
           "value": "Scheduled"
        }
      },
      {
      "status": {
          "id": "1.3",
          "value": "Recorded"
       }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`ids = [1,2,3,4]`

How can i fetch all documents having `id` in `ids` and at least one of `payments.status.value` equal to `Scheduled` state ?

I am using the following query but it's returning 0 records,

```
db.collectionName.find({$and:[{"value.id":{$in:ids}},{"value.payment.status.value":"Scheduled"}]})`
```

Comment: Well you don't really need the `$and` because ALL MongoDB query arguments are "already" an AND condition, but that query **does** return that document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify the name of the collection
 
so instead of this:

```
db.collection.find({
    $and:
    [
        {"value.id": {$in:ids}},
        {"value.payment.status.value":"Scheduled"}
    ]
})
```

you can write:

```
db.payments.find({
    $and:
    [
        {"value.id":{$in:ids}},
        {"value.payment.status.value":"Scheduled"}
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({
    'value.payment': {
        $elemMatch: {
            'status.value': 'Scheduled'
        }
    },
    'value.id': {
        $in: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
}, {
    'value.id': 1,
    'value.payment.$.status': 1
})
```